# An exercise using the open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $X$ a linear space with two norms $\|x\|_1\cdot\|x\|_2$. Also $X$ is complete with respect to both norms. If $\exists M>0$ (a finite constant) such that $\|x\|_2 \leqslant M\|x\|_1$ ,$\forall x \in X$, then $\exists N>0$ such that $\|x\|_1 \leqslant N\|x\|_2$ ,$\forall x \in X$.

This is my proof:

We define the linear operator $T:(X,\|\cdot\|_1) \longrightarrow (X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ to be
$Tx=x$.

$T$ is a bigective linear operator.

Also $T$ is continuous,because $\exists M>0$ such that $\|Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2 \leqslant M\|x\|_1$, $\forall x \in X$

From open mapping theorem we see that $T$ is an open map, in other words $T(V)$ is open for every open $V \subseteq X$.

Also $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}$ is continuous because $(T^{-1})^{-1}=T$ and $T^{-1}(V)$ is open for every open subset $V$ of $X$

Hence $x=T^{-1}x$ is a bounded linear operator ($T^{-1}:(X,\|\cdot\|_2) \longrightarrow (X,\|\cdot\|_1)$)

Is this proof valid or do i have to use a different approach ?(with the open mapping theorem)

Comment: It's correct. A shorter but concise argument would be: $T$ is a bijective linear operator from a Banach space to a Banach space, hence its inverse $T^{-1}$ is a bounded linear operator. (This is also known as the bounded inverse theorem.)

Comment: thank you,that is a nit argument but my instructor  gave me a hint tpo solve it by  applying directly the open mapping theorem

Comment: that's why i took this approach

Comment: The argument you had was exactly the proof of Bounded Inverse Theorem using the Open Mapping Theorem, but fair enough (: